# For what $k$ does $k \sin A + \cos 2A = 2k - 7$ have a solution?

Tags: trigonometry

> The equation $k \sin A + \cos 2A = 2k - 7$ has a solution, if:
>
> 1. $k >6$
> 2. $k>2$
> 3. $k<7$
> 4. $2\leq k\leq 6$

Although I did figure out the answer to be the last option using a bit of guess and all, but I need an exact way of solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Begin by grouping the terms involving $k$ on one side of the equation.  What does the coefficient of $k$ tell you about solutions?

Comment: Note that option 3. includes option 4., also option 2. almost includes option 4. (except for $k=2$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$k={7+\cos 2A\over 2-\sin A} ={8-2\sin^2 A\over2-\sin A}=2\cdot(2+\sin A).$$

Comment: (k/2)-2 = sin A
-------------------------------
-1<= sin A <=1
-----------------
solving further : 2<k<6